# How to Ask box overlaps textbox on Ask Question page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, asking-questions

In Safari on Mac, the "How to Ask" and "Formatting Reference" boxes overlap the textbox on the "Ask Question" page (on superuser, stackoverflow and serverfault).

The overlap disappers if you zoom in once (Cmd-+), but I consider this a bug that should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Safari 4.0.2 on Mac OS X and I can't reproduce this problem. I've played with the width of the window, zoomed in and out, both the entire page and only the text, and I don't see anything like what you're describing. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I can only reproduce with zoom at or below -2.

Comment: Sorry guys, turns out my Safari prefecences were to blame. I don't know how it got there (it's not accessible via the GUI, AFAIK), but `defaults delete com.apple.Safari WebKitMinimumFontSize` fixed the problem, when viewing /ask at actual size (a zoom friendly site would still be nice, and more accessible, though).